# python install snack package

Tags: python, audio, package

I have problem with installing Snack. I have windows 7 and python 2.7.6. When I istall it, this is output:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages>setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
copying tkSnack.py -> build\lib
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\tkSnack-2.2.10-py2.7.egg-info
Writing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\tkSnack-2.2.10-py2.7.egg-info
```

But when I run some program with Snack, I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\PROJEKTY\speech.py", line 1, in <module>
    from snack import *
ImportError: No module named snack
```

Is there any solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Newt or Snack in your Windows. Not the python binding but the library.